# ocaml-core equivalent of Unix.create_process

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'd like to port the following command from [Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) library to Jane Street's [Core.Std.Unix](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.21.00/doc/core/#Std.Unix) library.

```
Unix.create_process exec args Unix.stdin Unix.stdout Unix.stderr
```

That is, I have an executable `exec` and arguments `args` and want to run the process using the same in/out/error channels as the current process.

I can get close with `Core.Std.Unix.create_process ~exec:exec ~args:args`, but can't figure out how to connect the `stdin,stdout,stderr` returned by this function from core with the file descriptors used by the current process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `dup2` the returned descriptors to your current descriptors, but I'm not sure that this would work.

```
open Core.Std

let redirect ( p : Unix.Process_info.t ) : unit =
  let open Unix.Process_info in
  List.iter ~f:(fun (src,dst) -> Unix.dup2 ~src ~dst) [
    p.stdin,  Unix.stdin;
    p.stdout, Unix.stdout;
    p.stderr, Unix.stderr
  ]


let exec prog args : unit =
  let p = Unix.create_process ~prog ~args in
  redirect p
```

But there is another solution, that maybe applicable. Consider using just `Unix.system`, it should work just out of box.

Comment: Redirecting didn't work, but I'm sure `Core.Unix.system` would if I formatted the command for `sh`. For now I'll stick to the standard `Unix`. Thanks for helping me read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want to use the same channels as the current process, take a look at `fork_exec` in Core.Std.Unix:

```
val fork_exec : prog:string ->
                args:string list ->
                ?use_path:bool -> 
                ?env:string list -> 
                unit -> Core_kernel.Std.Pid.t
```

According to the docs,

> fork_exec ~prog ~args ?use_path ?env () forks and execs prog with args in the child process, returning the child pid to the parent.